# What am I missing in my flask restful api output is null and repeated

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-restful

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, fields, marshal_with,Api
import psycopg2

conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname=jobkhulyodb user=postgres password=password")
cur=conn.cursor()

app=Flask(__name__)
api=Api(app)

resource_fields = {
    'job_title': fields.String,
    'job_description': fields.String,
}

class Todo(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields, envelope='resource')
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        cur.execute("SELECT job_title,job_description from jobs")
        return cur.fetchall()


api.add_resource(Todo, '/foo', endpoint='todo')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

The api is build with **Flask, flask_restful and postgresql** 
Followed the documentation and as per it I created a resource fields and fetched the same resource from database using postgresql commands in the return fields. Where and what am I doing wrong the output looks something like in the picture. The database has 2 rows only but the result shows null and appearing 2 times.

**output**
[image]

Comment: Debug hint: try to print `cur.fetchall()` and see what you get.

Comment: Also, as a general rule, it's better to copy/paste than to use a screenshot.

Comment: [('jobs2','jobs description2'),('jobs3 ','jobs3 description')]. running on console.The print has exact data I need. but with large spaces, I guess its not a space issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting a list of tuple with `cur.fetchall()`, so this code must do what you need:

```
...
def get(self, **kwargs):
    ...
    list_ = []
    for elem in cur.fetchall():
        list_.append({ 'job_title': elem[0], 'job_description': elem[1] })
    return list_
```

Comment: though your misssed elem[1] but not a big deal. Thanks